# Square matrix whose determinant is already known

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, determinant

I was reading elementary algebra and suddenly I got stuck in a question which was

Write a $3*3$ square matrix $A$ whose determinant is $75$ ?

Now this can be done using hit and trial method or simply by using common sense. I'm wondering whether there is a standard method to solve this problem.
I'm trying a lot but couldn't find a general/standard method to solve this.
But I'm sure that there must be a method for such problems.

Comment: What are you asking for? You want one single matrix with given determinant or all such matrices?

Comment: take $\sqrt[3]{75}I_3$.

Comment: $$\left( \begin{matrix} 75 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$$

Answer (score 3):

How about :$$\left(\begin{matrix}
75 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$$
Or any other diagonal matrix where the product of the diagonal equals $75$. So the general method to find a matrix $A$ such that $det(A)= b$ is just to create a diagonal matrix where one entry on the diagonal is $b$ and the others are $1$.

Comment: I already know that it can be solved in this way. But I'm talking about any general method to get that.

Comment: This is a general method. You may do this for any value you want to get for the determinant. If you want a matrix where all entries are non-zero, then you should state that. But I dont see why you would go there...

Comment: this is just common sense. I was also solving it thus way.

Comment: The answer I provided solves your problem. If this is not the answer you sought then you should ask a more specific question.

Comment: I was just trying to say that I was also using the same method while I first attempted the problem. This is one of those method that everyone will come up with while trying to solve on their own and that's what happened with me. The purpose of the question was just seek different methods that can be employed to arrive at the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Then you should clearly state this clearly in the question. Also state what signifies a "different method".

Comment: I will take care about it next time and yeah I also liked the answer given by 5xum.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

1. What's the determinant of $\lambda\cdot A$, where $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ and $\det A$ is known?
2. Do you know of any matrix with a simple-to-calculate determinant?

Comment: So you want to use $\sqrt[3]{75}$ to find a $3 \times 3$-matrix with determinant $75$? Come on, you can't be serious. What would you do over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @Moos I am a bit surprised by your comment.

Comment: @MooS There are more ways to solve this task. Mine is one, and it works well over $\mathbb R$. I know full well there's more than one way to solve this problem. I don't see the need for your aggressive derogatory tone.

Comment: The methoed proposed in the other answer is natural and works over any field, while your method relies on the field to have enough roots. Math is all about beauty. Your answer is not beautiful, so it is my right to state this, isn't it?

Comment: @MooS It's your right to state this, and it's my right to state that you are stating that in a rude way. I agree my solution isn't the pretiest, but I wanted OP to come up with a solution with some thinking, instead of just writing down an answer. I also first thought of the solution in the proposed answer, but intentionally didn't. Also, the statement "Math is all about beauty" is false.

Comment: @MooS Math is also about diversity to help people learn the basics and apply it to other problems which can't necessarily be solved using only the most beautiful method.

Comment: @Evariste: So you can try to apply the two given answers to other problems, say surjectivity of $\det: \operatorname{Mat}_n(K) \to K$. The other answer easily solves this problem, while this answer will end in a deadlock or will even result in a false proof (If one does not care about the fact, that roots will not exist in general). I will not discuss this further, as 5xum admitted himself, that his answer is not the pretiest. I am fine with that.

Comment: @MooS This answer won't result in a false proof unless the mathematitian makes some mistake. And yeah, sure, this answer cannot be used in proving the surjectivity in your example. But it answers the original question. I don't see the point in getting all worked up about a question which isn't up to your aesthetic standards.

Comment: @5xum I totally agree with you. I asked this question just to get a hint and you provided me the same. Providing a solution is spoon feeding which is not a nice way to learn maths. Thank you.

Comment: My last comment was not meant to you, but to @Evariste. He tried to put the debate on a didactic level and talked about appliance to other problems. I showed him he is wrong, since the "natural next problem" after answering this problem (namely you can find a matrix with any given determinant) cannot be attacked with the same method. Nevermind, this is getting too long here.